# What is the event code for touching enter?

Tags: javascript, events

What is the event.code for tapping enter on a touch? The code that works on keyboards seems not to work on touch.

```
el.addEventListener( 'keydown', ev => {
  ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
  switch( event.code ) {
    case "Enter": ...
  }
}
```

You can test [here](https://go321.ch/)

- user:stacko
- pass:SO4u;22

Click on the link to edit and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.
It does work on a PC, but not on Android.

Comment: Can't you just print it and see what it is?

Comment: Have you checked the [doc: *Using Touch Events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events) ?

Comment: As this is on Android I don't know how to debug this

Comment: You can easily debug your mobile phone app if connected via USB data (and Dev mode ON) to your PC on Chrome. Google about it. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: @AlexandreB. Should I add an additional eh for touch keyboard events?

Comment: @theking2 could you please show the function you're using? This one line of code is not helpful. What eventName are you using specifically?

Comment: @AlexandreB. I might've missed it but mdn didn't say anything about keyboard touch events

Comment: I've edited the question with more context.

Comment: Actuallz I"m not interested in touch events perse but more in the keyboard event assocaited with tapping the keyboard. But in the mean time I got it working on Android as well as iPhones

Answer (score 2):

Android, Chrome returns `""` for `Event.code`.
Perhaps you'd like to try with `Event.key` instead:

```js
addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {

   console.log(event.key)     // "Enter" 
   console.log(event.keyCode) // 13
   console.log(event.code)    // ""
   console.log(event.which)   // 13

})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: @Rolo-c-buljan thanks that seemed to be the problem.`Event.code` indeed is empty om Android.

Comment: @theking2 I'm still not exactly sure for the reason. If I figure out something other than *"not yet implemented in all mobile browsers"* I'll update the answer. :\

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to solve this. Debugging on mobile devices is no victory march for caching and never being sure what code **actually** is being executed.
An excerpt of my code for the copy pasters.

```
"use strict";
/**  * a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.  
  * @param {string} selector  
  * @param {Element} [document] base  
  * @returns {(NodeList|Element|null)} 
  */ 
 const $ = (selector, base = document) => { 
   let elements = base.querySelectorAll(selector); 
   return (elements.length == 1) ? elements[0] : elements; 
 } 
  /** 
    * handle Enter and Esc events 
    */ 
   const keyEH = cellUrl.addEventListener("keydown", ev => { 
     switch (ev.key) { 
       default: break; 
       case "Enter": 
         console.log(`save data ${cellUrl.textContent}`); 
         break; 
       case "Escape": 
         endEdit(cellUrl, cellUrlValue); 
         break; 
     } 
   }, { passive: true, capture: false });
```

See the repo at (https://github.com/theking2/link-qr)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I see you used in the end Event.key. What was wrong with the already suggested answer?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for asking any questions about this multiple downvoted question. But ev.key seemed to be the most reliable way to handle key events

Comment: This is not answering my question. What was wrong with the already provided Answer?

Comment: It is not possible to watch what is writing in the console on a Android device

Comment: Yes it is. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/ . And this is still not answering my question. The only difference in the post and the answer if in that you used `Event.key`. So my question was: how is your answer different from the already provided one.